# Change height in an element

Tags: html, css

I have a word embedded file in SharePoint 2013 with the following element that refers to the Menu/Status bar:

```
<div class="WACStatusBarContainer loaded WacAirSpaceShared_BasicClass" id="WACStatusBarContainer" style="height: 22px; opacity: 1;">
```

I'd like to hide the bar and am able to in developer mode when i change th element to:

```
<div class="WACStatusBarContainer loaded WacAirSpaceShared_BasicClass" id="WACStatusBarContainer" style="height: 0px; opacity: 1;">
```

what would be the code to override the existing element?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
document.getElementById('WACStatusBarContainer').style.height = 0;
```

Comment: Thanks but do I need to place an !important tag?I placed the following into a script editor webpart:<script>document.getElementById('WACStatusBarContainer').style.height = 0;</script>
Still no luck...am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Browser developer modes also provide a "styles" inspector that will show you the css styles applied to an element. Usually you use the inspector's element selector to select the element so that you can see the applied styles, so you can see the css expression that you'll need to override.